# syntax error, unexpected kEND

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

```
def read_dbf(paste)
    #Lendo a pasta
    Dir.foreach(paste) { |name| 
        if(File.directory?(name))

            pasteSub = paste+"/"+name
            Dir.foreach(pasteSub) { |subname| 
                puts "Pasta: #{pasteSub}"
                puts subname } 
            end
        end
        }
    end
end
```

Error:  syntax error, unexpected kEND

I tried to create a block within a block and I think given problem. I am listing the contents of the folder and case folder for the content they access and read the contents of the folder as well.

Problem happened when I put the **"if"**

Comment: You have too many `end` statements.  Remove the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you add if and miss some end there. Try to use some editor for show you unexpected end.

```
def read_dbf(paste)
  #Lendo a pasta
  Dir.foreach(paste) {|name|

    if File.directory?(name)
      pasteSub = paste+"/"+name
      Dir.foreach(pasteSub) {|subname|
        puts "Pasta: #{pasteSub}"
        puts subname
      }
    end

  }
end
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to avoid deletion.